# Physical processing vs logical processing - Does the logical query processing change when indexes are involved?

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server, t-sql, indexing

I recommend this book.

This book explains in a great way the behavior of a sql query, but my doubt is,

1. How is a sql query processed when there are *indexes*, that is, *would this behavior change*?

My doubt is because I am a "teacher" and I would like to teach more details to my students.
[image]

2. This explains it in SQL Server, but I'm pretty sure it applies the same in MySQL, is that correct?

I am afraid to explain it and that this will change when there are indexes, **so I want to make sure if this does not change when there are indexes involved**.

Comment: You seem to be asking how a query is actually executed, but this chart does not answer it in the slightest. *All sorts of things* may greatly affect exactly what actual steps are chosen by the optimizer, and the selection rules change even between the editions of the same product, let alone between different products.

Comment: Indexes are relevant to the *physical* execution of a query, not its logical execution. As far as the logic is concerned indexes don't exist. Yes logical execution in MySQL is pretty much the same, bar the lack of `APPLY` `PIVOT` `UNPIVOT`. This graph also doesn't account for window functions. And I believe `TOP` and `ORDER BY` are in the wrong order. Not sure what the difference is between a "cursor" and a "set" at the bottom, that's not the normal meaning of those words.

Comment: "*Indexes are relevant to the physical execution of a query, not its logical execution. As far as the logic is concerned indexes don't exist.*" - Do you mean to say that the logical processing of this image still applies **whether or not there are indices**? @Charlieface

Comment: Yes, why wouldn't it? The *physical* execution is something else: the compiler needs to work out an efficient access method. But the logical execution doesn't concern itself with that as long as the results are the same.

Comment: "*Yes, why wouldn't it?*" - For example, speaking of transactions and locks, with indexes fewer records would be locked and without indexes more records would be locked @Charlieface

Comment: Again, locking is not really part of the logical execution of the query, and in the vast majority of cases locking should not affect the final result anyway.

Comment: I understand, could you pass me more questions (information) to understand more the differences? @Charlieface

Comment: This is a legitimate question, but not for Stack Overflow. The [guidelines state](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) clearly that this is a site for specific code problems, not general discussions.

Comment: Hi @Bill Karwin, I understand thanks, could you answer my main question, or **at least give me some guidance**, does the logical processing of queries change when indexes are involved?

Comment: I can only comment on MySQL, I don't know anything about Microsoft SQL Server. The processing is changed by indexes because the query execution will do lookups by index instead of table-scans, and sorting may become a no-op if the optimizer knows it's reading rows from the index in the requested order.

Comment: Aside: And there is always the edge case of performing an index _scan_, not _seek_. It may occur if the table has long rows and a search predicate can be resolved with less I/O, e.g. a `like '%foo%'` match on an indexed column. Or if a _covering index_ exists that provides all of the desired result columns, even if handling the search predicate(s) might be a bit clumsy.

Comment: Hi @HABO, so this diagram is explain **only** for table-scans cases (without indexes)?

Comment: so this diagram is explain **only** for table-scans cases (without indexes)? @Bill Karwin

Comment: @BillKarwin - you are describing **physical processing**. The diagram is about **logical processing**. Of course no RDBMS will implement all joins as cartesian products and then a subsequent filter either, Itzik Ben Gan uses this as a model to give a way to think about the logical processing order in a purely conceptual sense before the optimizer gets involved. Certainly he will state that it is not to be confused with the physical

Comment: In particular the OP seems to have skipped over this section in that chapter https://i.stack.imgur.com/npuCp.png

Comment: @jwa - I advise you not to teach this to others until you understand what it represents. This does **not** represent how SQL Server physically executes a query

Comment: Hi @Martin Smith, you have helped me a lot, this stole my sleep at times. logical processing (the one in the image of my question) 1) is **always** applied and 2) then physical processing follows?

Comment: I +1 the question since it's about understanding how a simple machine could resolve a query and that teaches students how the correct result can be achieved. However, in your course I would put emphasis in that no database would follow this conceptual strategy to run a query, since there's a ton of internal steps (and dirty tricks) the engine goes through to save resources and respond fast. And... indexes don't have anything to do with this conceptual understanding of a query.

Comment: That's right, I want to help people, but I still had doubts about it, I was not 100% sure. So, does the diagram in my question **only** explain the logical processing itself (the cases when no indexes are involved)? @The Impaler

Comment: @jwa The diagram depicts the conceptual/logical understanding of the execution of a query, with or without indexes. In fact the SQL Standard does not mention indexes at all in the spec. Indexes are related to the physical/actual execution, that is an advanced subject that greatly exceeds a "Database 101" course. Nevertheless, you can touch the subject of indexes with extremely simplified cases, to give an idea on how they work, but that's unrelated to the conceptual understanding of the query.

Comment: "*The diagram depicts the conceptual/logical understanding of the execution of a query, with or without indexes.*" - If I understood correctly, these are the steps by which any query would **in theory** be executed (explains how each clause itself is processed) but **in practice** SQL Server can "skip steps" in any clause-step, right? @The Impaler

Comment: I think if you teach some database theory, this is just fine of an explanation of how one should reason about a query you're looking at. But it's always good to mention that in reality, things are not that simple. Especially JOINs vs. WHERE can often be moved around a lot, depending on how the cardinality looks between the tables. A simple example is the old school: `select * from table1, table2 where table1.id = table2.id` in theory sql server could get all rows from table 1, then from table 2, and then do a WHERE, but in reality, this stuff is usually converted to a JOIN

Comment: @Charlieface - "cursor" walks through an ordered list of rows.  "Set" is an un-ordered list of rows.  I agree that `TOP` / `LIMIT` needs to be after `ORDER BY`.  For an ordered list, they make sense; for a "set" the "top n rows" would be somewhat umpredictable.

Comment: @jwa - Please don't double-post.

Comment: @jwa - OK, extra rows may be locked when there is not a suitable index.  I guess this could lead to a deadlock that would not otherwise occur.  Still, the output of the `SELECT` will be unaffected.

Comment: Don't teach from that page; it has an overwhelming number of steps.  Start with `SELECT 1;` then `SELECT * FROM tbl`, then `SELECT * FROM tbl where id=123`, add one clause at a time.  In this 3rd example, consider discussing `INDEX(id)`.  Etc, etc.

Comment: Hi @Rick James I posted twice because the community told me it was something not suitable for stackoverflow, sorry :(

Comment: Should have asked a mod to get it migrated, or we could have voted that.

Comment: _See also https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/333065/does-the-logical-query-processing-change-when-indexes-are-involved ._  (By now, need to merge the two discussions.)

Answer (score -4):

There are two main concepts here, keyed-in order of a query, and logical query processing order.

I will not list ALL existing query keywords, but here's the gist:

**Keyed-in Order:**

1. SELECT
2. FROM
3. WHERE
4. GROUP BY
5. HAVING
6. ORDER BY

**Logical Processing Order or Phases:**

1. FROM
2. WHERE
3. GROUP BY
4. HAVING
5. SELECT
6. ORDER BY

In short, NO, an index does not affect logical processing order. An index may take part in an execution plan if it exists but does not disrupt or change processing order in any way.

Comment: The keyed-in order is correct, but the logical processing order depends on the specifics of the query and can be all around the place. The execution plan details what actually happens in the end.

Comment: @TheImpaler What does that mean? The *logical* order does not change, the execution plan relates to the *physical* order.

Comment: @Charlieface Yes, that's what I'm sayng the physical execution related to the execution plan, that may have suffered widespread rewriting or could look upside down/inside out compared to the keyed-in sequence.